# saving to image to camera role advice needed

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I have images in my app id like user to save to cam roll, heres my code

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"england1.png"];  


UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, 
                               @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),    nil);
```

Compiler is complaining

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'

So my question is if i cant be nil or self what can it be?

Comment: Are you sure `img` is not nil ?

Comment: Did you implement `image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading skrams comment,  setting `img` to `nil` solved the problem, and also i had declared the image however it had been disconnected after some liberal undo action! So thanks both for your input.